# New line works for Gmail but not Outlook

Tags: email, google-sheets, outlook, gmail

Here's the code I'm using to send an email. It works perfectly when the email goes to Gmail (it sends four short tables with a line break between each one). However, when it goes to Outlook the second table (1,16) doesn't have new lines between the table entries while the other three tables still do (I don't know if it's related to those values specifically since the tables are identical in format). I understand there's probably some difference between email services, but is there a simple way to have the emails be consistent with new lines when arriving in both places? Thank you.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet4=ss.getSheetByName('Copy');
  var emailAddress = sheet4.getRange(2,12).getValue();
  var subject = sheet4.getRange(2,13).getValue();
  var message = sheet4.getRange(1,15,sheet4.getRange(31,15).getValues(),1).getValues().join('\n')+
                sheet4.getRange(1,14,3,1).getValues().join('\n')+
                sheet4.getRange(1,16,sheet4.getRange(31,16).getValues(),1).getValues().join('\n')+
                sheet4.getRange(1,14,3,1).getValues().join('\n')+
                sheet4.getRange(1,17,sheet4.getRange(31,17).getValues(),1).getValues().join('\n')+
                sheet4.getRange(1,14,3,1).getValues().join('\n')+
                sheet4.getRange(1,18,sheet4.getRange(31,18).getValues(),1).getValues().join('\n');
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: Try '\r\n' instead of just '\n'

Comment: This gives the same result... it works on Gmail but not Outlook. Everything is still on one line.

Comment: Does Outlook show "line breaks were removed..." message at the top of the preview pane?